# How to edit x-editable value after submit

Tags: javascript, x-editable

I want to edit the input value from the submitted form by performing encodeURI on the value so that the value will be a url type.

Example:

```
$("#smsapi").editable({
    type: "text",
    pk: 1,
    name: "smsapi",
    editValue: function(value){
        value = encodeURI(value);
        return value;
    },
    title: "Enter Your SMS Api Url Exluding message parameter",
    validate: function(
        if($.trim(value) == "") return "This field is required";
    }
});
```

Then continue with the submission.
Thank you for your response in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to modify the input by using the x-editable params method.

```
params: function(param){
        param._token = "{{csrf_token()}}";
        param.value =  encodeURI(param.value)
        return param
      },
```